# O que faz a invalidação de cache ser uma solução difícil?

Tags: algoritmo, cache

Há uma frase famosa:

> There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things
>
> -- Phil Karlton

Portanto ela fala que é difícil dar nomes para as coisas, o que tem um tom jocoso já que não é um problema de computação em si, mas realmente é um problema sério (geralmente porque a pessoa não entendeu o problema), e o outro problema, este sim de algoritmo é a invalidação de cache. Por que este é um problema complicado de resolver?

Comment: Putz, ia responder essa agora, mas estou com minha última resposta em cache ainda.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Os caches são os mogwais da computação: são fofinhos, simpáticos e nossos amigos, mas possuem as três regras que devem ser obedecidas:

- Ele não pode entrar em contato com a água;
- Mantenha-o longe da luz forte;
- Não importa o quanto ele chore, o quanto ele suplique, nunca, nunca o alimente após a meia-noite.

[image]

Descumpra umas das regras e você terá um [gremlin](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/GremlinStripeByInti.jpg/266px-GremlinStripeByInti.jpg) nas mãos.

---

Por mais estranho que pode parecer para alguns cache é do bem e veio para ajudar, mas exige atenção e cuidados especiais. Realizar o cache em uma aplicação tem dois pontos positivos muito importantes:

1. Diminui o tempo de resposta da aplicação, o que geralmente se converte em aumento de desempenho;
2. Aumenta a consistência de dados, pois a mesma operação possuirá o mesmo retorno;
3. Reduz a carga sobre o servidor, pois o cache passa a fazer boa parte do que o servidor faria;

O ato de realizar cache se resume a armazenar de alguma forma o resultado de um processo e reutilizá-lo *sempre* que o processo for realizado novamente e hoje praticamente tudo faz cache.

- A página que você acessa através do seu navegador é cacheada de tantas formas que é difícil listá-las todas. Ela é cacheada localmente no computador do cliente, é cacheada no servidor de proxy da empresa, é cacheada no servidor de cache, é cacheada pelo servidor web e é cacheada pela aplicação (e talvez outras formas mais).
- Computador faz cache de informações nas diferentes memórias que compõe o sistema: memórias L1, L2, L3, RAM e disco rígido.
- Nosso cérebro faz cache de muitas informações cotidianas: caminho casa/empresa é um exemplo, chega um ponto que fazemos esse caminho sem termos que decidir se ele é melhor.

Fora a complexidade de serem inúmeros tipos de caches a serem controlados, existe o problema de saber quando um cache deve parar de ser utilizado, que o ponto central da pergunta.

Para prosseguir com a resposta, teremos que imaginar uma situação hipotética composta por três atores: o cliente, responsável por efetuar a requisição, o cache, ator intermediário que realizará o cache das informações e o recurso, responsável por gerenciar as informações reais e gerar a resposta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde:

1. O cliente efetua a requisição, que passará pelo servidor de cache. Como é a primeira vez que a requisição é feita, o cache não possuirá a resposta armazenada, portanto repassa a requisição ao servidor de recurso;
2. O servidor de cache passa a requisição feita pelo cliente ao servidor de recurso quando não possui as informações cacheadas;
3. O servidor de recurso envia a resposta ao servidor de cache, que armazenará de alguma forma para uso futuro;
4. O servidor de cache repassa a resposta que recebeu do servidor de recurso ao cliente;
5. O cliente requisita novamente o mesmo recurso e novamente essa requisição será enviada ao servidor de cache;
6. Agora, como a resposta está cacheada, o servidor de cache consegue responder ao cliente sem depender do servidor de recurso;

E o que torna realmente difícil invalidar o cache é:

- São muitos caches. Controlar todos é custoso para a equipe de desenvolvimento;
- Informar o servidor de cache que ele deve invalidar as informações que possuem é um desafio;

Existem algumas abordagens mais comuns que buscam resolver, ou amenizar o problema.

#### Servidor de cache solicitar ao servidor de recurso quando foi a última atualização

Antes do servidor de cache responder o cliente com as informações cacheada ele solicita ao servidor de recurso quando foi a última alteração. Se as informações são as mais atuais, isto é, nenhuma alteração foi feita depois que as informações foram cacheadas, o servidor de cache responde o cliente com as sua versão cacheada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Curioso é que nesta abordagem o servidor de recurso ainda é acionado a cada nova requisição, o que acaba sendo um ponto negativo da solução, porém ainda é uma solução plausível dado que as informações transmitidas pelas mensagens 6 e 7 são bem menores que na 2 e 3, que trataram da requisição original. Outra vantagem desta solução é que facilita para sistemas distribuídos, em que o servidor de cache é fisicamente separado do servidor de recurso.

Essa abordagem é bastante comum nas aplicações web em que o navegador envia uma requisição de somente os cabeçalhos da resposta ao servidor e conforme os dados presentes nos cabeçalhos ele faz a requisição ou não do recurso. É comum justamente porque na web o sistema é distribuído e possui a comunicação unilateral, sendo o servidor de recurso enviar uma mensagem ao cliente para notificá-lo de mudanças.

#### Define-se um prazo de validade para as informações cacheadas

Outra forma comum de invalidar o cache é definir um prazo de validade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao receber a resposta do servidor de recurso, mensagem 3, o servidor de cache armazenará, junto com as informações, o prazo de validade. Assim, ao receber novamente a requisição do cliente, mensagem 5, basta ele verificar se data/hora são inferiores ao prazo de validade e, se forem, responde o cliente com as informações cacheadas; caso contrário, reenvia a requisição ao servidor de recurso e reinicia o processo.

A grande vantagem desta abordagem é que o servidor de recurso nem fica sabendo das requisições que foram respondidas com as informações cacheadas, desta forma cria-se uma independência maior entre os atores do sistema, ao passo que tem a desvantagem que se houverem alterações no servidor de recurso o resto do sistema não terá conhecimento até que o prazo de validade seja superado.

Buscando contornar as desvantagens deste método, há algumas abordagens secundárias que podem ser tomadas. Se a comunicação entre os atores for bilateral, o servidor de recurso pode enviar uma mensagem ao servidor de cache notificando as alterações de forma que este faça uma nova requisição ao servidor de recurso e atualize as informações cacheadas, independente de existir ou não uma requisição por parte do cliente; porém se a comunicação for unilateral, não há maneiras de o servidor de recurso enviar essa mensagem ao servidor de cache, então outra forma de amenizar o problema é definir um parâmetro na requisição que exige do servidor de cache a atualização das informações, independente se houveram alterações no servidor de recurso. Um exemplo disso é uma requisição HTTP que é tratada em um servidor de cache que com a presença do cabeçalho `X-No-Cache: True` ele trata a requisição de forma "By Pass", requisitando o servidor da aplicação e armazenando a resposta como cache. Assim, sempre que houver uma alteração no recurso, pode-se disparar uma requisição a partir de um cliente com o parâmetro devidamente configurado para atualizar as informações cacheadas. Ambas as abordagens demandam ter controle do servidor de cache, o que nem sempre ocorre.

#### Invalidação do cache por falta de uso

Aliadas às duas abordagens, mais a primeira do que a segunda, é possível fazer com que o servidor de cache invalide as informações armazenadas devido a falta de uso. Se uma requisição é feita agora, a resposta é cacheada e não é refeita por um largo período de tempo, o servidor de cache pode descartar as informações e requisitar novamente o servidor de recurso quando necessário. Está abordagem não leva em consideração alterações no servidor de recurso, por isso é mais comum ser aplicada como auxiliar de outras abordagens.

E isso estamos falando apenas da visão partindo do servidor de recurso, que é onde a equipe costuma ter controle e liberdade de gerenciar/projetar conforme os requisitos do projeto. Quando consideramos a partir do cliente podem existir barreiras que a aplicação é incapaz de passar.

É comum ter em empresas um serviço de proxy que controla o tráfego de informações da área interna com a área externa, controlando o que pode sair e o que pode entrar. Como há um serviço que trata todas as requisições, é comum que, além da auditoria de informações, também faça o cache das mesmas. Se o funcionário Fulano fez a requisição que precisava e obteve a resposta, quando a Beltrana precisar da mesma informação não haverá a necessidade de buscá-la diretamente do servidor de recurso; se o próprio serviço interno da empresa possui cacheadas as informações ele pode entregar a Beltrana as mesmas informações que foram entregues a Fulano. Sendo um serviço interno e próprio da empresa em questão, a equipe de desenvolvimento (da aplicação) fica a mercê do comportamento que a empresa definiu para o seu serviço interno. É um cache que não teremos controle. Deve partir da empresa em si desenvolver a lógica de invalidação de cache.

---

Resumindo, o cache foi criado por essência para ser validado, não invalidado, então é esperado (e desejado) que seja complicado o processo de invalidação. São coisas inversamente proporcionais pois a medida que você cria regras mais rígidas de cache, mais difícil será invalidá-las, ao passo que quando mais versáteis são as regras de cache, menos sentido faz utilizá-lo, visto que o servidor de recurso seria requisitado com maior frequência.

Matematicamente, o gráfico que caracteriza duas grandezas inversamente proporcionais é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na hora de projetar o sistema será necessário definir em que ponto da curva será trabalhado. Definir esse ponto de forma a atender todos os requisitos do projeto, que cacheie quando deve ser cacheado e que invalide quando deve ser invalidado é extremamente difícil. No geral, você sempre acabará cacheando mais do que devia, não conseguindo ver as atualizações em tempo real, ou cacheando de menos, sem tirar proveito de todos os benefícios do cache.

E como o [bfavaretto citou na resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/356342/5878), o problema se agrava porque tudo isso é recursivo. O servidor de recurso que consideramos na resposta pode ser outro servidor de cache, então um servidor de cache atuará como cliente de outro servidor de cache e fará cache do cache. *Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?* O problema passa, então, de como invalidar o cache a partir da aplicação para como invalidar o cache a partir do cache ou o cache do cache a partir de outro cache ou o cache do cache que está em cache em outro cache a partir do cache, etc.

Uma aplicação web facilmente chega a estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso a aplicação precisará invalidar o cache do servidor web, o servidor web precisará invalidar o cache do CDN, o CDN precisará invalidar o cache do proxy local, o proxy local precisará invalidar o cache do navegador e, finalmente, a versão atual da aplicação chegará ao cliente - isso se outra versão não for cacheada nesse meio tempo.

Answer (score 17):

> Esta resposta é baseada na minha experiência pessoal, no que aprendi na prática, e inclui inferências conceituais a partir dessa experiência. Veja exemplos detalhados ponto a ponto na [resposta do Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/358150).

Antes de falar da invalidação do cache, precisamos definir o próprio cache. De maneira simplificada, cache é uma cópia de acesso rápido a algo. Utiliza-se cache para evitar a repetição de alguma operação custosa, e o conceito de custosa depende do contexto. Por exemplo, sua CPU faz cache de dados para evitar leituras repetidas da memória, que seriam lentas em relação a ler do cache. Em outra escala, seu browser faz cache do conteúdo acessado, para evitar repetidas requisições HTTP aos mesmos recursos enquanto você navega.

Se por um lado o cache agiliza o acesso aos dados, por outro lado ele é uma cópia que tende a ficar defasada. E aí entra o dilema da invalidação: *quando* considerar que algo guardado em cache precisa ser atualizado? E, pior, a invalidação desses dados acarreta na invalidação de outros dados também? E a invalidação desse segundo nível invalida mais o quê?

Já deve ter dado para perceber que o problema é recursivo – claro que nem sempre, mas tem muito potencial pra ser. Então o grande problema é decidir quando parar. Isso em geral depende dos dados armazenados, da sua estrutura, do custo de pré-processamento desses dados antes do armazenamento em cache, do tipo de cache utilizado e dos recursos disponíveis. Ou seja, não existe solução universal. Quanto mais alto o nível do cache – no sentido de conter mais dados estruturados e inter-relacionados –, mais ele precisa ser "tunado" manualmente.

Existe ainda a questão da frequência ou gatilho de invalidação. Pode-se usar um tratamento similar ao de Garbage Collection em linguagens de programação, em que os dados vão sendo marcados como inválidos mas só são limpos (no caso de um cache, atualizados) em momentos de maior disponibilidade de processamento, ou na primeira necessidade de uso do valor atualizado. Outro caminho é o tratamento baseado em gatilhos, de maneira semelhante ao que existe em SQL. Algum evento na aplicação determina que o cache deve ser atualizado e dispara o processo.

É nessa linha que eu sempre interpretei essa citação. Provavelmente existem mais motivos. Fico na expectativa de uma resposta mais canônica de outro usuário.

Answer (score 5):

Meu ponto de vista é que a dificuldade está relacionado ao modelo de cache que se utiliza. Se for um cache distribuído tende a ser mais difícil de invalidar e manter sincronizado com os demais nodos. Outra dificuldade que vejo tem relação com os acessos ao cache. Se houver altíssima concorrência de leitura, bloquear novos leitores e esperar para invalidar pode causar efeitos colaterais com reflexos em toda a cadeia de sistemas que fazem uso do respectivo cache.
O cache deve ser projetado de acordo com a necessidade de uso visando identificar os casos de atualização que são críticos.