# O que são "caches" em relação as aplicações web?

Tags: php, cache, inphinit

No Inphinit Framework é possível usar cache nas respostas HTTP, veja um exemplo:

```
Route::set('GET', '/hello', function () {
    $cache = new Cache;

    if ($cache->cached()) {
        return;
    }

    return str_repeat('Hello, world! ', 1000);
});
```

Perceba que eu só preciso de um objeto da classe `Cache` em seguida basta chamar o método `cached()` para funcionar.

Entretanto, o próprio recurso de *cache* já me deixa algumas dúvidas em relação ao que ele representa para a minha aplicação.

## Dúvidas

1. O que são *caches* em relação as aplicações web?
2. Qual relação o cache tem com o protocolo HTTP? Eu sempre tenho que
   usar? Ele esta apenas vinculado as respostas?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que faz a invalidação de cache ser uma solução difícil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356320/5878)