# Por que é difícil dar nome as coisas?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, convenções-de-nome

Lendo esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356320/o-que-faz-a-invalida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-cache-ser-uma-solu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-dif%C3%ADcil) eu me deparei com a seguinte frase:

> There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

O foco é no segundo problema que é dar nome as *coisas*, que parece estar se referindo a variáveis, funções ou qualquer outra coisa em programação. Claro que isto pode ser um tipo de "piada" também, vendo que parece simples dar nome para coisas xD. Entretanto, quando percebemos, isso se torna uma tarefa um pouco complicada.

Pelo menos para mim, muitas vezes é complicado dar nome para as funções e variáveis, até mesmo classes, sempre me enrosco no significado que aquele código deve passar e me faz pensar muito na interpretação dele, diferente da matemática onde a [forma ajuda a visualizar os padrões](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24241/why-do-mathematicians-use-single-letter-variables#comment52289_24241).

Veja alguns exemplos de nomes de métodos que ficaram muito longos e que eu tive dificuldade de nomear no passado:

- `EstaNoCaixaAbertoDoDiaAtual(int idBaixaServico)`
- `Caixa.ObterIdDoCaixaAbertoNoDia()`
- `ExisteRegistroDeAberturaPendente()`

E há até funções nativas do PHP como `geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region` ou `mailparse_determine_best_xfer_encoding` que possui um nome um pouco longo e complicado. Isto pode se repetir em outras linguagens e bibliotecas, mas não vou listar todas aqui.

Eu poderia até diminuir os nomes criando classes ou fazendo um outro tipo de separação, o que me leva a pensar que a programação orientada a objetos é para ajudar a nomear as coisas no final das contas (claro que vai muito mais além), e toda esta verbosidade deixa a tarefa de nomeação muito custosa, sem dúvidas é o que parece.

Posto este cenário, eu gostaria que a minha pergunta fosse respondida.

## Pergunta

- Por que é tão dificil nomear as coisas, existe alguma forma de
  contornar este problema?

Comment: Li seu texto 2x e não consegui pegar o foco da questão. Vc quer dizer: nomear variáveis, funções, classes? Se for isso, eu, humildemente e com todo respeito, acho a parte mais fácil do código.

Comment: Putz, ia responder essa t, mas estou com p última x em i ainda e não consegui entender o que as variáveis t, p, x e i são.

Comment: No geral, acho que o processo de nomear requer que a solução este devidamente estruturada; e estruturar a solução requer domínio da mesma; e dominar a solução requer domínio do problema; e dominar o problema requer conseguir entender o nome das coisas;

Comment: Por via das dúvidas, nomeie as coisas com nome de pelos do rosto (Barba, Bigode, Cavanhaque) e delegue ao revisor achar o nome adequado!

Answer (score 3):

Computação às vezes é sobre modelar a realidade, que é extremamente complexa, em um algoritmo, que no fundo é operações aritméticas com fluxo de controle. A conversão da realidade pro código é um desafio completamente diferente da comunicação da sua solução e da intenção do seu algoritmo. Muito dessa comunicação vem do nome que você dá às coisas.

Note também que nomear as coisas é uma atividade de **design** que você faz enquanto programa. Não é fundamentalmente difícil, mas criar nomes curtos e claros sobre aquilo que você está representando é sim uma tarefa complexa. Ainda assim, é uma habilidade que pode ser treinada e melhorada. Ler código dos outros é um bom exercício, tanto para aprender quanto pra pensar em como poderia melhorar.

## Sugestões

Outra coisa, que é ponto de debate, é que na minha opinião português é uma língua muito verbosa. Nomear classes e variáveis em inglês levam a um código mais conciso, pois inglês usa menos preposições, tem palavras geralmente mais curtas e sinto que há maior padronização, mas isso é uma questão discutível.

Sua função está muito longa porque é muito específica. No exemplo a seguir eu também deixo a função mais flexível para aceitar um parâmetro que especifica o dia, assim é mais fácil reutilizá-la em outras partes do código.

```
- EstaNoCaixaAbertoDoDiaAtual(int idBaixaServico)
+ IsOnOpenCash(int idService, Date date=None)

- Caixa.ObterIdDoCaixaAbertoNoDia()
+ Cash.GetOpenCashId(Date date=None)
```

Note que eu coloquei `date=None`: algumas linguagens como Python permitem colocar argumentos padrão. Então a chamada para saber se o caixa está aberto no dia atual seria com apenas um parâmetro, igual na versão original. Eu gosto de deixar assim quando a função vai ser majoritariamente chamada numa condição (ex. dia atual), mas em algumas situações não. Então podemos especificar explicitamente o dia apenas nas situações atípicas. Isso é ok desde que esteja bem documentado.

Compare a chamada para essas funções no caso em que queremos informações sobre o dia atual:

```
EstaNoCaixaAbertoDoDiaAtual(42)
IsOnOpenCash(42)

Caixa.ObterIdDoCaixaAbertoNoDia()
Cash.GetOpenCashId()
```

São 28 caracteres a menos!