# Forçar limpeza do CACHE CSS e JS

Tags: php, javascript, css

Eu trabalho com um servidor. Sempre que altero meu CSS/JS e envio para o servidor, ele não muda diretamente a versão do meu arquivo, fica armazenado em cache. Ou seja, sempre tenho que limpar o cache e então ver a alteração que acabei de fazer, o que acaba gastando muito tempo. Existe algum comando ou informação no arquivo que eu possa forçar ele a sempre limpar o cache?

Preciso de uma solução com PHP

Comment: Você trabalha com PHP ou só HTML e JS puro?

Comment: Trabalho com PHP tbm amigo @LucasAyrosa

Comment: Vinculada: [O que faz a invalidação de cache ser uma solução difícil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356320/5878)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, isso é bem fácil de ser resolvido, faz uma função simples no php que sempre adicione um parâmetro no final do seu arquivo, pode utilizar o rand

```
function getFileHash($file) {
        //Gera número aleatório para a versão
        return $file . '?v=' . rand(10000, 1000000000000);
    }
```

Comment: Isso geraria um nome de arquivo a cada requisição e faria com que fosse cacheado múltiplas versões do mesmo arquivo. Se o objetivo é apenas desativar o cache, isso deveria ser feito configurando devidamente o servidor. Querer contornar adicionando um número aleatório é gambiarra. Isso pode ser feito quando se tem, de fato, o controle da versão do arquivo e a mesma só muda quando houver alterações.

Comment: @Woss nunca havia pensado por esse lado sempre utilizei nos meus códigos dessa forma. Obrigado pelo comentário em casos onde cache não é necessário farei dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Usando com PHP fica bem simples, você pode criar uma variável de versionamento e chama-la na query string dos arquivos.
Por Exemplo:

1. Criar uma variável em um arquivo config.php:

```
<?php
define(“Version”, “1”);
?>
```

2. Aplicar a variável nas query strings da chamada dos arquivos

```
<link  rel=”stylesheet” href=”/style.css?v=<?php echo Version; ?>” type=”text/css” />
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/javascript.js?v=<?php echo Version; ?>“></script>
```

Dessa forma sempre que alterar essa variável o navegador reconhecerá que é um arquivo novo e não dará o problema com o cache.

---

Caso não queira, por algum motivo, trabalhar com essa forma de versionamento, pode também obrigar o navegador a sempre baixar os arquivos a cada acesso:

```
<link  rel=”stylesheet” href=”/style.css?<?php echo time(); ?>” type=”text/css” />
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/javascript.js?<?php echo time(); ?>“></script>
```

Porém essa abordagem pode atrapalhar um pouco o carregamento do site caso os arquivos sejam pesados e atrapalhar a experiência do usuário que acessa frequentemente, por ter essa demora por baixar todos os arquivos sempre para exibir uma página que ele já havia entrado.